# How to tune a training schema for a different data set in Caffe?

Tags: computer-vision, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

Currently I am following the [caffe imagenet example](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/imagenet.html) but apply it on my own training data set. My dataset is about 2000 classes and about 10 ~ 50 images each class. Actually I was classifying vehicle images and the images were cropped to the front, so the images within each class have the same size, the same view angle(almost).

I've tried the imagenet schema but looks like it didn't work well and after about 3000 iterations the accuracy was down to 0. So I am wondering is there a practical guide on how to tune the schema?

Comment: 0 accuracy shows that your training algorithm is incorrect

Answer (score 2):

You can delete the last layer in imagenet, add your own last layer with a different name(to fit the number of classes), specify it with a higher learning rate, and specify a lower overall learning rate. There does exist an official example here: http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/finetune_flickr_style.html

However, if the accuracy was 0 you should check the model parameters first, perhaps it's an overflow